# Spark SQL - UDF for calculating the difference between two date and times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

Is there any Spark SQL UDF available for calculating the difference between two date and times?

Comment: what kind of difference ? number of days ?

Comment: @eliasah : Number of days or Number of hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function for now (Spark 2.0) to compute the difference between two dates in number of hours, but there is one to compute the difference in number of days :

> **def
>   datediff**(end: Column, start: Column): Column
>   Returns the number of days from start to end.
>   Since
>   1.5.0

Ref. [Scaladoc - functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).

Answer (score 4):

I created one on my own. Here is how it goes:-

```
def time_delta(y,x): 
    from datetime import datetime
    end = datetime.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    start = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    delta = (end-start).total_seconds()
    return int(delta/(60*60*24))
```

This takes in the two dates y and x and return the result in days. I used the below code to register it:-

```
f = udf(time_delta, IntegerType())
sqlContext.udf.register("time_diff", time_delta)
```

It works like a charm. Here is an example:-

```
df = df.withColumn("Duration", f(df.end_date, df.start_date))
df.show()
```

Results are:-

```
Column<unix_timestamp(end_date, %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)>
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
| id|           end_date|         start_date|state|city|Duration|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
|  1|2015-10-14 00:00:00|2015-09-14 00:00:00|   CA|  SF|      30|
|  2|2015-10-15 01:00:20|2015-08-14 00:00:00|   CA|  SD|      62|
|  3|2015-10-16 02:30:00|2015-01-14 00:00:00|   NY|  NY|     275|
|  4|2015-10-17 03:00:20|2015-02-14 00:00:00|   NY|  NY|     245|
|  5|2015-10-18 04:30:00|2014-04-14 00:00:00|   CA|  SD|     552|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
```

I am also able to use it in Spark SQL:-

```
%sql select time_diff(end_date,start_date) from data_loc
```

And the results are:-
[Spark SQL results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sfEV.png)